# jQuery adding multiple text boxes

Tags: jquery, textbox

I wonder if anyone could help me.

I have a web page where there are some text boxes (dynamic amount, could be 3, could be 30) and each one a user can enter a number and I have a total count at the bottom.

At present I have this:

```
$('input.qty').change(function() {
// Get the current total value
var total = $('#total');
// Update it with the changed input's value
total.val(parseInt(total.val()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<td><input type="text" class="qty" value="0" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="qty" value="0" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="qty" value="0" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="total" value="0" /></td>
```

which adds fine first time, but when you start changing values it simply adds the new amount to the total rather then adding all the boxes up.

How can I sort this? Perhaps use the each attr somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through them all using a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and sum them up, like this:

```
$('input.qty').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input.qty').each(function() { sum += parseInt(this.value, 10); });
  $('#total').val(sum);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7AVbm/), if you want it to calc on every keypress then use [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead of [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7AVbm/1/).